# How to fix box-sizing: border-box; back button not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have upgrade both Avada and child theme; I have a custom back button added to the gallery container. After the upgrade, only half the button is displaying. I had a look using the Chrome Inspector and, when I untick `box-sizing: border-box`, the button is showing properly. The child theme style.css & page code are shown below the following settings.

How can Ifix it? I have very little knowledge of CSS and HTML - just starting.

FYI: the my WP website copy is installed on my local server using docker WP V5.4.1/PHP_7.4/Apache image.

```html
.post-content #bwg_container1_0 #bwg_container2_0 [class*='bwg_back_']{
 /* text-indent: -99999999px; */
 width: 130px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 height: 35px;
 position: relative;
 color: #fff !important;
 background: rgb(191, 3, 9);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 3, 9) 0%, rgb(253, 4, 12) 49%, rgb(191, 3, 9) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgb(191, 3, 9)), color-stop(49%, rgb(253, 4, 12)), color-stop(100%, rgb(191, 3, 9)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 3, 9) 0%, rgb(253, 4, 12) 49%, rgb(191, 3, 9) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 3, 9) 0%, rgb(253, 4, 12) 49%, rgb(191, 3, 9) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 3, 9) 0%, rgb(253, 4, 12) 49%, rgb(191, 3, 9) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(191, 3, 9) 0%, rgb(253, 4, 12) 49%, rgb(191, 3, 9) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#bf0309', endColorstr='#bf0309', GradientType=0);
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-family: "Share";
 padding: 8px 40px;
 line-height: 20px;
 font-weight: 300 !important;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
 transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

page code

```html
[fusion_builder_container hundred_percent="no" equal_height_columns="no" menu_anchor="" hide_on_mobile="small-visibility,medium-visibility,large-visibility" class="" id="" background_color="" background_image="" background_position="center center" background_repeat="no-repeat" fade="no" background_parallax="none" parallax_speed="0.3" video_mp4="" video_webm="" video_ogv="" video_url="" video_aspect_ratio="16:9" video_loop="yes" video_mute="yes" overlay_color="" video_preview_image="" border_size="" border_color="" border_style="solid" padding_top="" padding_bottom="" padding_left="1px" padding_right="0px"][fusion_builder_row][fusion_builder_column type="1_1" layout="1_1" background_position="left top" background_color="" border_size="" border_color="" border_style="solid" border_position="all" spacing="yes" background_image="" background_repeat="no-repeat" padding_top="" padding_right="0px" padding_bottom="" padding_left="" margin_top="px" margin_bottom="0px" class="" id="" animation_type="" animation_speed="0.3" animation_direction="left" hide_on_mobile="small-visibility,medium-visibility,large-visibility" center_content="no" last="true" min_height="" hover_type="none" link="" first="true"][fusion_text][Best_Wordpress_Gallery id="10" gal_title="Projects"]

[/fusion_text][/fusion_builder_column][/fusion_builder_row][/fusion_builder_container]
```

Comment: Bro only show relevant part of code where you think problem is ... posting whole content might not help.

Comment: above is the style.css setting for the button only and the button code in the page editor for the container. where can i find the box-sizing: border-box configuration? and what can cause box-sizing: border-box to affect the issue i'm experiencing?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, no change was done was working before the upgrade. Probably some settings have to be readjusted due to the new theme changes.  Any idea where/ what I can check?  
Thank you

Comment: my site url  below where you can see the issue (you need to click on one of the photos to see the back button issue)  https://avsion.com.au/projects/

Answer (score 0):

i managed to fixed it changed the padding from padding: 8px 40px; to padding: 8px 30px;